Parse Platform dashboard unauthorized when accessing the parse-server
What are the possible problems that is causing {"error":"unauthorized"} in the Parse Dashboard when accessing the dashboard is accessing: http://192.168.2.10:1337/parse/serverInfo
version: '3'
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgis/postgis
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_MULTIPLE_EXTENSIONS=postgis,hstore,postgis_topology,postgis_raster,pgrouting
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - postgis-data:/var/lib/postgresql

  parse:
    image: parseplatform/parse-server
    environment:
      - PARSE_SERVER_APPLICATION_ID=parse
      - PARSE_SERVER_MASTER_KEY=parse@master123!
      - PARSE_SERVER_DATABASE_URI=postgres://postgres:password@postgres/postgres
      - PARSE_SERVER_MOUNT_PATH=/parse
      - PARSE_SERVER_ALLOW_INSECURE_HTTP=true

    ports:
      - '1337:1337'
    entrypoint: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "sleep 5;  node ./bin/parse-server"] #sleep few seconds for postgres to come up
    depends_on:
      - postgres

  parse-dashboard:
    image: parseplatform/parse-dashboard
    ports:
      - '4040:4040'
    environment:
      - PARSE_DASHBOARD_TRUST_PROXY=1
      - PARSE_DASHBOARD_COOKIE_SESSION_SECRET=AB8849B6-D725-4A75-AA73-AB7103F0363F
      - PARSE_DASHBOARD_SERVER_URL=http://192.168.2.10:1337/parse
      - PARSE_DASHBOARD_MASTER_KEY=parse@master123!
      - PARSE_DASHBOARD_APP_ID=parse
      - PARSE_DASHBOARD_APP_NAME=MyParseApp
      - PARSE_DASHBOARD_USER_ID=admin
      - PARSE_DASHBOARD_USER_PASSWORD=password
      - MOUNT_PATH=/dashboard/
    command: parse-dashboard --dev
    depends_on:
      - parse

volumes:
  postgis-data:


my guess is db configs aren't being loaded properly. have you tried using the basic options instead of environment variables. the docs suggest that the env vars you've used should work but the docker getting started might be a good thing to test first
